# How to use pre_get_posts and post__in

Tags: wordpress

i want to use pre_get_posts on a query. My code is following:

```
public static function getAuthorArticles($query) {

  if ($query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query()):
    $author = get_user_by('slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ));
    $authorID = $author->ID;
    $authorPostIDs = self::getAuthorsPostIDs($authorID);
    $coAuthorPostIDs = self::getCoAuthorsPostsIDs($authorID);
    $postIDs = array_unique(array_merge($coAuthorPostIDs, $authorPostIDs), SORT_REGULAR);

    if(get_query_var('paged')):
      $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    elseif (get_query_var('page')):
      $paged = get_query_var('page');
    else:
      $paged = 1;
    endif;

    $query->set('post_type', 'any');
    $query->set('paged', $paged);
    $query->set('post__in', $postIDs);
    $query->set('orderby', 'date');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');

  endif;
}


add_action('pre_get_posts', __CLASS__ . '::getAuthorArticles');
```

In the $postIDs array are post ids of co-author's article located. 
But it still doesn't show posts which author is assigned as co-author. it only shows the posts which written by author. I'm sure in the postIDs array are the right ids located.

Can some one make any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to share the code for the methods `getAuthorsPostIDs` and `getCoAuthorsPostsIds`, as this is where your question seems to lie unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem ist not about that functions. They deliver the correct id's. But "post__in" doesn't affect the query.

Comment: Okay, good to know. That is odd. Do the other query vars seem to affect the query? orderby, order, paged, post_type, etc. Make sure those are working too. If nothing is working, then the issue could be it isn't firing at all, or is being overriden. If it is JUST post__in not working, that's a deeper issue. Also, try passing the second argument of add action like this: `array( __CLASS__, 'getAuthorArticles')`

Comment: Do the other query vars seem to affect the query?  Yes, they affect the query. post__in appears to be overwritten. Can i avoid it in someway?

Comment: Did it work at all when you changed the function call to an array like I mentioned? Try majorly upping the priority. Try making the priority like 10000000 and see if it still isn't working.

Comment: Did it work at all when you changed the function call to an array like I mentioned? 

No it didn't. 

Also i tried to make the priority 999999999 not affected. 

only "post__in" is overwritten...

Comment: Sorry, but there must be something else going on specific to your environment because your code is valid. Check the global `$wp_filter` to see if any functions are hooked in there later in load.

Comment: The problem is still there. But i think wordpress only shows the posts of the author on authors page. So, i wanted to show all the posts, which the author is assigned as co-author via ACF-Plugin. Is there anyway to force to show any posts on authors page?